# How to Decrypt field values and show them in Salesforce standard report while running a report?

Tags: report, salesforce, encryption

I ve following situation:

I ve an object and one of its fields holds encrypted values of actual values. Now while running the salesforce standard report i want to decrypt them and show the actual values in report output.I dont know if its possible to call a function to decrypt the encrypted values just after clicking on "Run Report" button and then decrypt them and show them in report output.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so - the only possible ways I can think of would be:

1. Schedule the report to run as a user which has the `View Encrypted Data` permission.
2. Utilize `Apex` / `Visualforce` (`OutputText`) to render the report.